# What is the best way to implement images into blog posts in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave, blogs

I am building a blog website. After a user is logged in the user is able to create blog posts. On the blog index page there should be a thumbnail image of the blog post.

As user it would be nice if I could upload and implement images into the blog dynamically meaning I can freely decide where an image should be rendered in the blog post. I thought about using carrierwave and creating a images model.

I have not implemented a rich text editor like for example TinyMCE because I know I only can implement images with an image url on TinyMCE.

**Is there a way to upload images and use it dynamicly within a form?**

Comment: what's the problem you see with carrierwave? any reason why you are not using it? Both carrierwave and paperclip work perfectly fine

Comment: @jenvvv the user has to be able to decide where he wants to render his image on the blog post and I can not achieve this with only carrierwave or can I? Thanks allot

Comment: Uhm, I understand now what you mean. You mention TinyMCE but, have you tried to use tinymce-rails-imageupload? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only reason you were not using TinyMCE was because you couldn't properly upload images but inserting an url, tinymce-rails-imageupload allows you to upload images within a post.

[tinymce-rails-imageupload Github](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload)

And here's a tutorial about it where you can guide yourself through:

http://blog.active-bridge.com/how-to-implement-nice-image-uploader-to-tinymce